# Symfony 2.8 - hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string

Tags: symfony, php-7, symfony-2.8

I've updated symfony from 2.7 to 2.8 and get info from few users (of course for me everything is working fine) that they can't log in. The error message is:

```
11921#11921: *37980489 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, null given in /www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BasePasswordEncoder.php on line 84" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: domain.com, request: "POST /action/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "domain.com"
```

Php version is 7.0.19 (but it didn't change in update).

Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Acme\Entity\Frontuser:
            algorithm: sha512

providers:
    acme_db:
        entity:
            class: Acme\Entity\Frontuser
```

Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/action/login", name="gologin", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        'Acme:Security:Form.html.twig',
        [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'login_error' => $error,
        ]
    );
}
```

Form.html.twig

```
<form id="form-login" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path('gologin') }}">
<div>
    <label for="modal-login-email">{{ 'email'|capitalize }}</label>
    <input type="email" autocomplete="email" name="_username" value="{{ last_username|default() }}" id="modal-login-email" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="modal-login-password">{{ 'password'|trans|capitalize }}</label>
    <input type="password" name="_password" id="modal-login-password" required>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
<button id="login-button" type="submit">{{ 'login'|trans }}</button>
```

And using ajax login made similar to this https://www.brainvire.com/add-ajax-login-form-symfony2-project/. Can anyone try to help/understand this?

Comment: can you provide  full security.yml ?

Comment: try to change sha1  to bcrypt

Comment: changing to bcrypt don't broke anything? I mean my saved salts and passwords?

Comment: so make a backup first :)  ,  i had similar  problem some time ago  , and in my case changing  to bcrypt  helped ( but  i have app in  dev  - there wasn't any real data  in db )

Answer (score 0):

```
$hash_equals = $known_string != '' ? hash_equals( $known_string, $user_string ) : false;
            
if ( $hash_equals ) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. It's not even clear where this code should be.